# TypeORM in NestJS - how to get MySQL nested object like in the entity and do a 'where' query on subrelation?

Tags: javascript, mysql, nestjs, typeorm

I have tried to do this as QueryBuilder:

```
const ret = await getManager()
  .createQueryBuilder(Order, 'o')
  .leftJoinAndSelect(PartOfOrder, 'p', 'o.id = p.orderId')
  .where(':purcharser = o.purchaserId', { purcharser: purcharserId })
  .andWhere(':supplier = p.supplierId', { supplier: supplier.id })
  .andWhere('p.status = 0')
  .getRawMany();
```

And have result like:

```
{
    "o_id": "3454d7fe-072a-4983-a811-5ce45106488c",
    "o_date": "2021-09-01T07:30:07.000Z",
    "o_amount": 20598,
    "o_paymentId": "b8c937f0-4d61-4f84-8760-ebb0ec5bc35f",
    "o_purchaserId": "5adeb8ed-6703-4e82-a7e3-2b10d8fbf912",
    "p_id": "8c6bfc56-aa7a-4d9a-a872-7ccd370a7137",
    "p_amount": 200,
    "p_delivery": 0,
    "p_message": "",
    "p_date": "2021-09-01T07:30:07.000Z",
    "p_status": 0,
    "p_pickupCode": 8073,
    "p_supplierId": "e41aff94-343c-4062-b55a-90bf1b3e3695",
    "p_orderId": "3454d7fe-072a-4983-a811-5ce45106488c"
}
```

Here I have flat response, I need to have nested from SQL.

Below I have a `find()` query and I don't know where to put `where` in nested object.

```
const ret = await Order.find({
  relations: ['partsOfOrder', 'partsOfOrder.products'],
  where: { purchaser: purcharserId },
});
```

**Edit**

My Order entity relation prop:

```
@OneToMany(
  type => PartOfOrder,
  entity => entity.order,
  {
    cascade: true,
    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
  },
)
@JoinColumn()
partsOfOrder: IPartOfOrder[];
```

I can filter it on any loop but servers will die, and really need to do this in SQL

Answer (score 0):

In your first solution try to use `getMany()` instead of `getRawMany()` and you'll get a nested object.

Comment: It returns only main instance in query, in this case i got only data from Order entity.

Comment: It's weird, probably, you should specify selection additionally (add `.select('o', 'p')` after `.leftJoinAndSelect`)

Comment: I have one good solution:

    const ret = await Order.createQueryBuilder('order')
      .innerJoinAndSelect('order.partsOfOrder', 'part')
      .innerJoinAndSelect('part.products', 'products')
      .where(':purcharser = order.purchaserId', { purcharser: purcharserId })
      .andWhere(':supplier = part.supplierId', { supplier: supplier.id })
      .andWhere('part.status = 0')
      .getMany();


PS tell me how to paste code as formatted in comment?

Comment: In comments, you can just wrap it in ` brackets, but it would be one line peace of code